# Issues forcing IE9 to render like IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to render a webpage in Explorer as IE8, since IE9 is doing a great mess with CSS and not showing the @font-face.

I read the Microsoft Documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and other related topics like [IE9 does not at all care about 'X-UA-Compatible' meta tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813947/ie9-does-not-at-all-care-about-x-ua-compatible-meta-tag) and [Force IE9 to emulate IE8. Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811801/force-ie9-to-emulate-ie8-possible) and none resolved my issue, either I am very dumb (witch can be) or I can't find the problem.

The webpage is: karactermania.com/web2012/betty and I'm using the CMS Textpattern to build it.

I tried with:

```
<!-- Enable IE8 Standards mode -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />

<!-- Enable IE8 Standards mode -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE8" /> (as I found some examples written with and without the "=")

<!--[if IE 9]>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE8" >
<![endif]--> (desperate attempt)
```

Complete HTML declaration:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="es" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<head>

<!-- Enable IE9 Standards mode -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE8" />
```

If anyone can point where the error is and how can I fix it, will earn my eternal gratitude :)

Thanks

Comment: Why not tackle the actual issue with `@font-face` not working? What's your `@font-face` code?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you. My X-UA-Compatible header was ignored. I found the solution in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391220/meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-8-ignored-in-richfaces-webapp)

The x-ua-compatible header has to be in the head section, **before all other elements except for the title element and other meta elements**