# input text value is not being set on internet explorer (jsf)

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf, jsf-1.2

I have a form with a single field in it:

```
<div class="base-label-input">
    <div class="label-align dark-label">
        <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.negociacao_cadastro_cliente_cadastrar_insc_estadual}"
            for="inscr_estadual" /><span class="estilo-asterisco estilo-asterisco-add"><h:outputText
                value="#{msg.campoSimbolo}" /></span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-align">
        <h:inputText id="inscrEstadual" tabindex="1"
            required="false" maxlength="19"
            disabled="false"
            value="#{actionInscricaoEstadualCliente.inscricaoEstadual.inscricaoEstadual}"
            size="50" label="Inscr_Estadual">
        </h:inputText>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="base-label-input">
    <a4j:commandButton styleClass="button"
        value="#{msg.inserir}" type="submit"
        onclick="javascript:Richfaces.showModalPanel('progressWaitModalPanel');atualizarImagem();"
        action="#{actionInscricaoEstadualCliente.inserirInscricaoEstadualLista}"
        eventsQueue="eqCadastroUsuario" tabindex="2"
        reRender="grdInscricaoEstadual, inscrEstadual">
    </a4j:commandButton>
</div>
```

When i hit the button using chrome, the value is set in the object. But when i do the same with internet explorer, the value is not being set. Any ideas?

(The form is quite large...so i put the inputtext and the button)

Comment: done any basic debugging, like checking the browser's javascript console for errors?

Comment: Yup...no errors found...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @JoaoVictor provide all versions you are using, which JSF/Chrome/IE versions ?

Comment: @Tarik jsf 1.2, IE 11, chrome 40.0.2214.111

Comment: what about Richfaces version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding Richfaces 4.x [Technical Requirements](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_5_X/Developer_Guide/en-US/html/chap-Developer_Guide-Getting_started_with_RichFaces.html#sect-Developer_Guide-Getting_started_with_RichFaces-Technical_Requirements) the minimum JSF implementation required is 2.x (2.1.28 or higher for `javax.faces.jar` and   2.1.10 or higher for `myfaces-impl.jar`), as you said that you are using JSF 1.2 I will assume that your Richfaces's version is 3.x.x.

RichFaces 3 is only supported in Internet Explorer 8 or less, if you want to use IE 11 you need to set the [meta tag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff966528%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which enables you to control the document compatibility's mode:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
```

Comment: I've tested with this meta tag and no cigar...in fact, there was another meta tag with the same content, but it was like content="IE8"

Comment: @JoaoVictor could you follow the steps in that answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12391922/4170582 ?

Comment: I've created the filter class and put it inside web-inf folder, but i can't map the class in the web.xml file...it says that the class is non-existent or something.

Comment: put the compiled class  `/WEB-INF/classes` or just let eclipse do it, you can follow the steps from here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info

Comment: I've managed to make it work. I've put IE=EmulateIE10 in the content atribute. I'll run more tests and see if it's really solved. But i have one more question: the minimum IE version that the users will have to use is the 10th?

Comment: @JoaoVictor No you need to use the 8, as I told you RichFaces 3 is only supported in Internet Explorer 8

Comment: The thing is i don't think that the final users will have the IE8. My best guess is that they will use the 10th version at least.

Comment: @JoaoVictor they can use any IE explorer they want, your filter will render the page as if it is IE 8, So you need to put `IE=EmulateIE8` and it will work in any later IE version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71200/discussion-between-joao-victor-and-tarik).